# php Mac Address check format

Tags: php

I am getting the mac of the user from the url. What I'm trying to do is match to see if the address is genuine. Cause I'll be running it against a database and I don't want to run it if it's not the right format.

This is what I have so far:

```
if (isset($_GET['mac'])) { 
    if (strlen($_GET['mac']) == 18) { 
        $get_mac_filtered = preg_replace('/^([a-fA-F0-9]{2}:){5}[a-fA-F0-9]{2}$/', '',$_GET['mac']);
            if (preg_match('/^([a-fA-F0-9]{2}:){5}[a-fA-F0-9]{2}$/', $_GET['mac']) == $get_mac_filtered) {
                echo 'Got a mac match! '.$get_mac_filtered;
            }else {
                echo 'Sorry !=';
            }
}else {die();} }
```

I'm guessing the problem is somewhere in here `(preg_match('/^([a-fA-F0-9]{2}:){5}[a-fA-F0-9]{2}$/', $_GET['mac']) == $get_mac_filtered)` because it returns `else`

Comment: If you're checking for matches against the DB anyway, won't that return `false` if the format is incorrect?

Comment: What's the problem with the above code?

Comment: It will. But i'd rather not bother the DB until I got the format right @OliverCharlesworth

Comment: @andrewsi I am guessing it is somewhere in here `(preg_match('/^([a-fA-F0-9]{2}:){5}[a-fA-F0-9]{2}$/', $_GET['mac']) == $get_mac_filtered)` cause it returns else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line. It does nothing useful:

```
$get_mac_filtered = preg_replace('/^([a-fA-F0-9]{2}:){5}[a-fA-F0-9]{2}$/', '',$_GET['mac']);
```

As written, this replaces anything resembling a valid MAC address with… nothing. This is almost certainly not what you want to do here.

Instead, on the next line, compare the results of `preg_match()` to 1. (It returns 1 if the regular expression matches, and 0 if it does not.)

Comment: Isn't it risky to use `&_GET` straight into the DB?

Comment: If I use something like this `$get_mac_filtered = preg_replace('/[^a-fA-F0-9]/', '',$_GET['mac']);` it removes the `:` from the address.

Comment: @Borsn Risky? Not if you're following best practices and using a parameterized query. And in any case, the regular expression would reject anything unwanted.

Answer (score 8):

Available since PHP 5.5, the best way to validate a MAC address is using `filter_var` with the constant `FILTER_VALIDATE_MAC`:

```php
var_dump(filter_var('FA-F9-DD-B2-5E-0D', FILTER_VALIDATE_MAC));
// string(17) "FA-F9-DD-B2-5E-0D"

var_dump(filter_var('DC:BB:17:9A:CE:81', FILTER_VALIDATE_MAC));
// string(17) "DC:BB:17:9A:CE:81"

var_dump(filter_var('96-D5-9E-67-40-AB', FILTER_VALIDATE_MAC));
// string(17) "96-D5-9E-67-40-AB"

var_dump(filter_var('96-D5-9E-67-40', FILTER_VALIDATE_MAC));
// bool(false)

var_dump(filter_var('', FILTER_VALIDATE_MAC));
// bool(false)
```

So you can just do:

```php
if (false === filter_var($_GET['mac'], FILTER_VALIDATE_MAC)) {
    throw new \Exception('Invalid mac address');
}
```